# Misunderstanding Clojure's require

Tags: import, clojure

I have 2 files: enviro.clj and point.clj; both in the same folder.

I want to import point.clj into enviro.clj.

enviro.clj:

```
(ns game-of-life.enviro
  (:require [game_of_life.point :as point]))

(defrecord Enviro [cells dims])

(defn create-dead-enviro [width height]
  (Enviro.
    (replicate (* width height) :dead)
    (point/Point. width height)))
```

point.clj:

```
(ns game-of-life.point)

; A 2D point representing a coordinate, or any pair of numbers
(defrecord Point [x y])
```

With this set-up though, Intellij (with Cursive) is saying that it can't resolve `point/Point.` inside of `create-dead-enviro`. It does however suggest importing it. If I allow it to auto-fix it, it changes the top of enviro.clj to:

```
(ns game-of-life.enviro
  (:require [game_of_life.point :as point])
  (:import (game_of_life.point Point)))
```

From what I've read though, `import` is only for Java interop to import a Java class; it's not used to "import" a Clojure namespace.

What am I missing here?

## Edit

Still no. I changed enviro.clj to:

```
(ns game-of-life.enviro
  (:require [game_of_life.point :as point]))

(defrecord Enviro [cells dims])

(defn create-dead-enviro [width height]
  (Enviro.
    (replicate (* width height) :dead)
    (->Point width height)))
```

And I'm still getting an "cannot resolve" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of specialness around records and only records where you need to import them if you want to use the `(recordName. args)` java interop constructor form.

if you use the `->Enviro` helper function you don't need to add the extra import.

```
user> (defrecord Enviro [cells dims])
user.Enviro

user> (->Enviro 1 2)
#user.Enviro{:cells 1, :dims 2}
```

and it's a bit more clojure'ish do do it that way anyway.

Recort types are a quick way to define a named type to interacting with java libraries that expect this. They are also slightly faster for field access than maps. When using records keep in mind that if you `conj` some extra field into them in the course of working with them, then remove it later, they will silently stop being records and revert back to being normal maps. In general use records when you know you need them for java interop or in very tightly optimized code that you have already very carefully benchmarked (I have never seen this in practice). They have some value for documentation as well.

here is an example of using the `->recordName` function *instead* of the java interop form.

```
user> (ns game-of-life.point)
nil
game-of-life.point> (defrecord Point [x y])
game_of_life.point.Point
game-of-life.point> (in-ns 'user)
#namespace[user]
user> (require '[game-of-life.point :as point])
nil
user> (point/->Point 1 2)
#game_of_life.point.Point{:x 1, :y 2}
```

Because the java interop form generates a names class outside the usual namespace onventions you need to import that class iff you use the `className.` constructor or use an explicit call to `new` to create your record object. if you use the automatically created function `->className` then you don't need to use import

Comment: I'll try it in a sec. Thanks.

Comment: missing the `point/` on the last line of your example. ->Point is a normal clojure function that is defined for you by the defrecord macro. you need to refer if just like any other clojure function (it's not special syntax)

Comment: you also have _'s instead of -'s in the require call. it should be `(ns game-of-life.enviro
  (:require [game-of-life.point :as point]))` the file that you type a namespace into has it's -s replace with _s because the JVM classloader insists on this, but the require should match spelling in the ns form

Comment: !!! Oddly enough, I used `(require '[game-of-life.point :as point])` instead of `(ns game-of-life.enviro
  (:require [game_of_life.point :as point]))` and it worked.

Comment: running `(clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand-1 '(ns game-of-life.enviro (:require [game_of_life.point :as point]))))` will explain why in more detail. in short the ns macro expands to some calls to require